# Microsoft Flow - Document Approval

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to create a 2-stage approval in Microsoft Flow, a fairly trivial task in SharePoint Designer.

- I added a SharePoint trigger : "When file is created or modified (properties only)" and configured it for my site and document library
- Then I added a "Start an approval" task and configured it to send the approval to a user

When I tried to test the workflow, it fails on the first step, with the following error message:

```
Status code: 400
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "The required field \"Funding Type\" data type is not supported\r\nclientRequestId: 22a926d7-1b8b-4a97-bffe-cd6deca42327",
  "source": "https://<website>/Policies-And-Procedures/_api/SP.APIHubConnector.GetUpdatedListItems",
  "errors": [
    "-1",
    "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPConnectorException"
  ]
}
```

The FundingType field it fails on, is a Site Column linked to a Termset and is set as Multivalue.

It's a bit disappointing to have it fail on such a trivial scenario.
Hoping, I am missing something small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this (https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Forum/data-type-is-not-supported/td-p/24248), site columns with multiple values are not supported.

I changed my column to accept only a single value and that fixed it.

Comment: You can mark your question as answered (by your own answer).